# Tkinter grid is resetting the background color

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, background

So I'm beginning with tkinter and there is a problem I cannot solve, when I use the grid to define where I want my stuff to be, every cell in the grid will not have the desired background color.

Better to show than to explain too much :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT = ("arial", 20)

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        #self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        #self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.configure(background='black')

        main_container = tk.Frame(self)
        main_container.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky = "nsew")
        main_container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        main_container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        main_container.configure(background="black")

        menu_bar = tk.Menu(main_container)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff = 0) 
        file_menu.add_command(label = "Save settings", command = lambda: popupmsg("Not supported yet!"))
        file_menu.add_separator()
        file_menu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = quit)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file_menu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu = menu_bar)

        self.frames = {}

        for fr in (MainPage,):
            frame = fr(main_container, self)
            self.frames[fr] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, pointer):
        frame = self.frames[pointer]
        frame.tkraise()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Main Page", fg = "white", bg="black", font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Main Page2", fg = "white", bg="black", font = ("Arial",8))
        label2.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = 'ne')

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Page 2", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button2.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'nswe')

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Exit", command = quit)
        button3.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'nswe')

app = Main()
app.geometry("1280x720")
app.mainloop()
```

So as you can see, from here :
[screen](http://prntscr.com/l6d7z1)

The background inside the grid is resetted and I have added background modifiers everywhere I could, I still cannot get it to work

PS : I know I should uncomment the 2 lines in the beginning for it to work like I want but this is just to show that the frame background is working but the grid one is not the same for some reason

Thanks in advance,
Shraneid

Comment: Add this line to your `MainPage` class. `self.configure(background='black')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for `grid` to change the color of anything. `grid` isn't a "thing" and doesn't itself have a color or change the color of anything. If you want the background of `MainPage` to be black, you need to set it to black.

If you want it hard-coded, just add it when calling the `__init__` method of the superclass:

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black")
```

Comment: Oh ok I thought it was inheriting it's background from the Main class, Thanks !

Comment: @Shraneid: `MainPage` inherits its background from `tk.Frame`. The default background color for `tk.Frame` is gray.

Answer (score 1):

> The background inside the grid is resetted and I have added background modifiers everywhere I could, I still cannot get it to work

The background is not resetting. The frame contains its own background color so you need to tell your `MainPage` class (aka the frame) what color you want it to be.

```
class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # Add this line here
        self.configure(background='black')
```

Comment: Oh ok I thought it was inheriting it's background from the Main class, Thanks !